# Tool tip for static plotline in y-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I have drawn two static lines in my chart to indicate high and low range. I could keep labels for the line but I can't keep a tooltip for the the static line. Is there any way I can do this?

```
yAxis: {
  plotLines: [{
    value: 70,
    width: 1,
    color: '#68AF46'
    label: {
      style: {
        color: '#FE7246',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      text: '70',
      align: 'right',
      x: -10,
      y: 16
    },
  },
  {
    value: 180,
    width: 1,
    color: '#FE7246',
    label: {
      text: '180',
      align: 'right',
      style: {
        color: '#FE7246',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
    },
  }]
}
```

I find no property to keep tooltip for plotlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add two additional dummy series and hide them under the plot lines:

```
series: [{
    data: [1, 50, 100, 200]
}, {
    data: [70, 70, 70, 70],
    showInLegend: false,
    lineWidth: 0.5,
    color: 'transparent',
    marker: {
        radius: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'plotLine1'
    }
}, {
    data: [180, 180, 180, 180],
    showInLegend: false,
    color: 'transparent',
    marker: {
        radius: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'plotLine2'
    }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2Ln05yes/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this functionality exists by default in Highcharts, but you could create it by listening for the `mouseover` event on your `plotLine` and creating the tooltip manually. Then, on `mouseout`, just dismiss the tooltip.

Here's an example with a plotLine with tooltip on y = 50:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    styledMode: true
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Tooltip On PlotLine'
  },
  yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
      value: 50,
      width: 1,
      color: '#68AF46',
      label: {
        style: {
          color: '#FE7246',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        text: '50',
        align: 'right',
        x: -10,
        y: 16
      },
      events: {
        mouseover: function(e) {
          var series = this.axis.series[0];
          var chart = series.chart;
          var PointClass = series.pointClass;
          var tooltip = chart.tooltip;
          var point = (new PointClass()).init(
              series, ['PlotLine', this.options.value]
            );
          var normalizedEvent = chart.pointer.normalize(e);

          point.tooltipPos = [
            normalizedEvent.chartX - chart.plotLeft,
            normalizedEvent.chartY - chart.plotTop
          ];

          tooltip.refresh(point);
        },
        mouseout: function(e) {
          this.axis.chart.tooltip.hide();
        }
      }
    }, ]
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
  },
  series: [{
    data: [10, 30, 20, 60, 80]
  }]
});
```

```css
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

#container {
 height: 400px;
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.highcharts-tooltip-box {
 fill: black;
 fill-opacity: 0.6;
 stroke-width: 0;
}

.highcharts-tooltip text {
 fill: white;
 text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: couldn't find `axis` and `options`. Do I need to import anything ?

Comment: Hmm, no, you shouldn't need to. I just modified the code you provided a bit and added the event handler for mouseover. It should be working in the snippet. If my answer doesn't fit your needs, see if the one by @ppotaczek helps.